# Mark pull request with conflicts as merged not closed

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

Please take a look at https://github.com/the42/bevaddressapi/pull/2

I had merge conflicts, pulled locally, resolved the conflicts and pushed to master. However the Github UI only allowes me to mark this Pull request as closed whereas I  want to mark it as merged.

Is there no way to mark a pull request as merged when there are merge conflicts and I have to manually resolve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's marked as closed, accept or not

Many projects' pull request is Open or Closed

Comment: I see, thank you. I consider this a bit unfortunate. However I understand that if a merge cannot be automatically merged and requires manual intervention, it is difficult to automatically accept it as merged.

Comment: The pull request should be accepted by the owner, or the project will be out of control

Comment: I am the owner but as soon the pull request requires manual interaction it can only be closed whereas those which can automatically merged display as "merged". This leaves a wring picture. But, Ok, I thought I am doing something wrong but apparently not.